# Android - Query SQLiteLocalStore

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, android-sqlite, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services to download an Azure Mobile Sync Table to be stored locally on my device as a SQLiteLocalStore Database but I want to query that? How would I go about it? I've looked and many people use a cursor but they use this on a Database that they have specifically built, not one that comes direct from Azure Mobile Services?

To put this into context here is my situation:
I have a spinner which displays Column1 (Table1.Description) of my table, and when one of the options is selected I want to display Column2 (Table1.Code).
So I want to query the Local SQL on the Android device with a query to the following effect

```
SELECT 
     Table1.Column2 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE 
    Table1.Column1 = "Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()"
```

Is someone able to help or point me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

"'"+Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'" use this

Comment: Hi Bansal, thanks for the answer, I think I need to make my question more clear. I can't understand how to query the Local SQLiteLocalStore?

Answer (score 0):

The reference to the SQLiteStore is a SyncTable, which you get by `Client.GetSyncTable<T>()`.  You can use standard LINQ queries to query the table:

```
var table = Client.GetSyncTable<ModelForTable1>();
var search = Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
var results = table
    .Where(record => record.Column1 == search)
    .ToList();
```

You can use pretty much any LINQ statement and it gets turned into the appropriate SQL statement for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Adrian, I'm trying to implement this but I cannot get a .where condition to be allowed on my MobileSyncTable? I'm as equals direct to the Sync Table but am unsure where I'm going wrong? Code is below.

Comment: table = mMobileClient.getSyncTable("CodeItem");
                    search = mSpinnerCode.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    results = mCodeTable
                            .where(record => record.Code == search)
                            .ToList();

Comment: MobileServiceTable<CodeItem> table = mNTSClient.getTable(CodeItem.class);
                            search = mSpinnerCode.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            List<CodeItem> results = table.where().field("Code").eq(search).execute().get();