# Custom queries with SQLiteLocalStore Azure

Tags: java, android, azure, sqlite, azure-mobile-services

How to make custom Queries with SQLiteLocalStore from microsoft.windowsazure package in Android with Java?

I found [this issue related to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532931/android-query-sqlitelocalstore), there is no `where` method for my `MobileServiceSyncTable`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Android library is no longer supported.
2. The Android library does not support custom queries.